# PhoneGap + android, Pre-populating database not working.

Tags: android, database, cordova, populate

I am creating a PhoneGap (android) project. In this I am populating a database table from reading a text file. (say my Package name is com.santu.jdictionary). But when I try to copy this 0000000000000001.db , as well as Databases.db files to /data/data/com.santu.jdictionary/app_database/file__0/ folder I get an error.

```
 void copy(String file, String folder) throws IOException 
  {

   File CheckDirectory;
   CheckDirectory = new File(folder);
   if (!CheckDirectory.exists())
   { 
    CheckDirectory.mkdir();
   }

      InputStream in = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(file);
      OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(folder+file);

      // Transfer bytes from in to out
      byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
      int len; while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) out.write(buf, 0, len);
      in.close(); out.close();

  }
```

Secondly, I have been able to successfully copy this file to the above said folder thru a phoneGap plugin, but after copying also PhoneGap is unable to use this file. 
When ever I try to open Database with this code, a new .db file is initialized (namely 0000000000000002.db)

```
 db = window.openDatabase("database", "1.0", "JDictionary", 10000000);
 db.transaction(populateDB,errorCB, successCB);
```

So Where am I making mistake.

thanking in advance.

santu ghosh

Comment: Dumb question - but why not simply open the db the 'normal' way, and then read the text file and initialize the db?

Comment: Hi Mr. Dumb, I mean Mr Raymond.

Comment: Um.... seriously? I was trying to help. I can't see you getting much help with an attitude like that.

Comment: @RaymondCamden he might have thought you were calling his question dumb, not that you were the one asking a dumb question

Comment: Ah, well, if so, Santu, I was definitely NOT calling you dumb. ;)

Comment: I am surprised that nobody could answer my simple question. When I started that project my knowledge of creating a db in android and re-using the same db in PhoneGap was like Zero. 

Now I can say it was a basic question only, instead some people called it a dumb question, and provided no help.
 
If it was a dumb question then there will not be so many articles on the net for pre-populating a db in android and using the same in PhoneGap. And why should I  use it the way you suggest? 
why? Obviously you did not understand the question, but still you have to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the soultion ultimately in ::

[link](http://gauravstomar.blogspot.in/2011/08/prepopulate-sqlite-in-phonegap.html)

I hope everyone who commented here will read this article before trying to help others